# What's the thermal time constant/capacitance of a 1/4W resistor?

Tags: resistors, thermal, time

I can't find it anywhere, what is the thermal time constant or thermal capacitance of a standard discrete 1/2W resistor?

A table with other resistors of different power ratings would be nice, too.

Comment: I don't think there is a "standard", you'd have to check manufacturers data sheets.

Comment: So here's a fun fact.  The Heat capacity of everything is about 3 J/(K*cm^3). (+/-50% or so) So measure the volume and you can make a guess.  The time constant will depend on the thermal resistance which is material and geometry dependent.  Unless you are pulsing the R's for a very short time, you care more about it's thermal conductivity to the outside world, than you do about it's heat capacity.  SMD resistors with big copper pours on the ends are good.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold - "The Heat capacity of everything is about 3 J/(K*cm^3). (+/-50% or so)" That is an amazing rule-of-thumb! Why did my school teacher never tell me that? +1

Comment: @gbulmer, Grin.  I've been designing these thermal conductivity, heat capacity stages.  (plastics are a bit lower)    So I think this is due to the fact that above the debye temperature, every atom in a solid has ~3kT of energy.  And then the number density (#atoms/cc) of stuff, is not all that different.  (OK I'll post my table as an answer.. and kill it if someone complains.)

Comment: If you're going for very high peak-to-average power ratios, the internal construction (and its thermal conductivity) may be important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK a table of volumetric heat capacity for @gbulmer.

```
Material      Heat capacity (J/(K*cm^3)) at 300K. 

Aluminum      2.42 

Copper        3.4 

Iron          3.5 

Al2O3         3.0 

G-10          2.7 

Nylon         1.7
```

Addition: Guesstimate of time constant for through hole resistor.
So let's just assume the whole thing is made from ceramic, say Alumina.  Thermal conductivity is k = 30 W/(m* K) = 30mW/(mm* K) (millimeters will be easier for me) And make the diameter 2 mm (area = ~3mm^2) and the length 6mm.   Then thermal conductivity (end to end) is

R = 1/k * l/Area = 67 K/W.  Then the heat capacity is 3J* volume (cm^3) = 18 mJ/K.  Now we need to scale the thermal resistance by some amount.  I'll guess 1/2 (say 30K/W) but this is most likely not enough.  (I'll over estimate the time constant.)  Then the time constant is 30k/W*18mJ/K = 0.54 seconds.  So that seems OK, but maybe high.

As an interesting aside I once tried to measure how much of the heat in a through hole resistor comes out through the leads.  The answer was basically zero, except with very small heat input... and the numbers were still "in the noise".   Through hole resistors are meant to cool by convection around the body.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't make an HTML table, but there are various ways of getting fixed spacing and preserved spaces.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thanks.  The <pre> changes the font and </pre> brings it back?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [Table of Specific Heat Capacities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Table_of_specific_heat_capacities), which include even more substances.

Comment: Actually this is to calculate the time constant so I would need the thermal resistance but since it wasn't actually my question (and that apparently it's geometry dependant, hence has to be specified in datasheets) this one is sorted out by that very useful rule of thumb (+ more precise tables).

Comment: @MisterMystère,  What's the resistor.  The surface mount ones are on Alumina, mostly and you can get a guesstimate* of the time constant.  Heat capacity times thermal resistance.  Take the end to end thermal resistance and divide it by 1/2 (maybe) because the heat is generated everywhere.            *Hey when did guesstimate become a "real" word?

Comment: The resistors are what look like "standard" 0.5 and 0.25W through hole resistors such as this one http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/through-hole-fixed-resistors/7078091/ or that one http://uk.farnell.com/te-connectivity/lr0204f110k/resistor-metal-110k-0-25w-1/dp/2329857

Comment: @MisterMystère, OK I edited my answer with said guesstimate.